# Correct us of 'each' in jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have 2 Caldera forms on a single page and I have this snippet of jQuery used to manipulate some of the markup.

```
$('.ss-form-fields').prependTo('.caldera_forms_form');
```

The problem is that both forms have the .ss-form-fields element and the result is that I'm getting elements duplicated.

So I tried this;

```
$(".caldera-grid").each(function(){
$('.ss-form-fields').prependTo('.caldera_forms_form');
});
```

.caldera-grid being a class at the top of the form markup.

Should this have worked (because it didn't) or am I doing it all wrong?

EDIT

The purpose of the .prependTo was to bring the .ss-form-fields to the top of the markup so that I could use child selectors in css as I couldn't get them to work otherwise. Without the prepend the markup looked like this;

[image]

With the prepend I could make the markup look like this;

[image]

If there is a better way of achieving a similar result i would love to hear about it.

Comment: Please also share relevant HTML code also to provide better solutions to this.

Comment: Semi-related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887834/getting-the-value-of-the-input-field-using-jquery/59888053#59888053  <= answer covers using contextual lookups for dom manipulations.  Both of your prependTo statements are executing in the global scope.

Comment: Are you really wanting $('.caldera-grid .ss-form-fields').prependTo('.caldera_forms_form');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like intended if you do it this way:

```
$(".caldera-grid").each(function(){
   let fields = $(this).find('.ss-form-fields')
   $(this).find('.caldera_forms_form').prepend(fields);
});
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehbyro1c/) with the relevant structure of your page.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)